# MySQL - Select value only once based on another field

Tags: mysql, sql

My database schema is like following:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  priority ENUM('low', 'medium', 'high') NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (id, title, priority) VALUES (1, 'test', 'medium');
INSERT INTO test (id, title, priority) VALUES (2, 'test', 'high');
INSERT INTO test (id, title, priority) VALUES (3, 'test2', 'low');
```

And my query is like following:

```
SELECT * FROM test 
ORDER BY FIELD(priority, 'high', 'medium', 'low');
```

I would like to do a `DISTINCT` on field `title` based on `priority` field. For example, if there are two or more data with the same `title`, I would like to select only the one with the highest priority, so in my case the expected results would be the data with id 2 and 3. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
WHERE FIELD(priority, 'high', 'medium', 'low') =
          (SELECT MIN(FIELD(priority, 'high', 'medium', 'low'))
           FROM test t2
           WHERE t2.title = t.title
          );
```

EDIT:

I didn't think that priorities could be repeated.  The above can be modified to use the `id`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
WHERE id = (SELECT id
            FROM test t2
            WHERE t2.title = t.title
            ORDER BY FIELD(priority, 'high', 'medium', 'low')
            LIMIT 1
           );
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's a problem. For example, if two data have the same title and priority, they are both selected. Instead, I would expect to select just one of the two.

Comment: @Bob, try adding `Group by t.title, t.priority` to bottom of this query.

Comment: @Bob . . . That is solved by using `id` in the subquery rather than the priority.  It actually simplifies the query a little.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Table and sample data

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  priority ENUM('low', 'medium', 'high') NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (id, title, priority) VALUES (1, 'test', 'medium');
INSERT INTO test (id, title, priority) VALUES (2, 'test', 'high');
INSERT INTO test (id, title, priority) VALUES (3, 'test2', 'low');
INSERT INTO test (id, title, priority) VALUES (4, 'test2', 'low');
INSERT INTO test (id, title, priority) VALUES (5, 'test2', 'low');
INSERT INTO test (id, title, priority) VALUES (6, 'test', 'low');
INSERT INTO test (id, title, priority) VALUES (7, 'test3', 'low');
INSERT INTO test (id, title, priority) VALUES (8, 'test3', 'high');
INSERT INTO test (id, title, priority) VALUES (9, 'test3', 'medium');
```

Query

```
SELECT Max(t2.id)  AS ID,
       t1.title    AS Title,
       t1.priority AS Priority
FROM   (SELECT title,
               Min(priority) AS priority
        FROM   test
        GROUP  BY title
        ORDER  BY Field(priority, 'high', 'medium', 'low')) t1
       INNER JOIN test t2 using (title, priority)
GROUP  BY t1.title,
          t1.priority;
```

Output

```
+-----+--------+----------+
| ID  | Title  | Priority |
+-----+--------+----------+
|  2  | test   | high     |
|  5  | test2  | low      |
|  8  | test3  | high     |
+-----+--------+----------+
```